# c# application auto start windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer, uac

I have a project in which i have added an installer project. i was following this ([custom installer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19560/Launching-Your-Application-After-Install-using-Vis))

I added a custom installer class. One purpose of this is to add the program to the registry for auto startup when any user logs in. I am running visual studio as administrator (says so on the top of visual studio - Note: in computer management i am not an administrator). my laptop however also uses an application called powerbroker . To install applications i right click and select run elevated. From reading other posts run elevated is not the same as administrator and therein probably lies the issue.

Anyway the problem is that:
In visual studio no error is generated (code runs fine) to add the key (i wrote a seperate aplication to test this. The key however does not get written -- i do not understand why?

When i put the code in my installer and run elevated no error is thrown and the key is not written either - at least if it errored out and rolled back the install....

i did try to set the key for the currentuser instead and that works fine but its of no use to me....

i also created a local user with who is a member of the administrators and that did not have access either.

To sum up what i am trying to figure out is:
How can i throw an error that the registry write failed and rollback the install (remember the code does not currently throw an error below under elevated privaleges but doesnt actually work)

Is there a fix to this problem?

thanks
damo

**C# installer class code**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;



namespace OffLine.Installer
{
    // Taken from:http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/
    // system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx
    // Set 'RunInstaller' attribute to true.

    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class InstallerClass : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public InstallerClass()
            : base()
        {
            // Attach the 'Committed' event.
            this.Committed += new InstallEventHandler(MyInstaller_Committed);
            // Attach the 'Committing' event.
            this.Committing += new InstallEventHandler(MyInstaller_Committing);
        }

        // Event handler for 'Committing' event.
        private void MyInstaller_Committing(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            // **** Beta Only **** Set program to autostart
            try
            {

                RegistryKey add = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

                add.SetValue("FactoryAuditEventNotification", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());             

            }

        }

        // Event handler for 'Committed' event.
        private void MyInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName
                (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
                Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(
                  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\FactoryAuditEventNotification.exe");
             }
            catch 
            {
                // Do nothing... 

            }
        }

        // Override the 'Install' method.
        public override void Install(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Install(savedState);
        }

        // Override the 'Commit' method.
        public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Commit(savedState);
        }

        // Override the 'Rollback' method.
        public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Rollback(savedState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: View permissions on a registry key HKLM\..\Run. Open regedit. Click the key. On the Edit menu, click Permissions. Try use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) for tracing access to hklm\..\run key.

Comment: That's a whole lot of code to write a registry value.  Have you considered just using the Registry table?

Comment: @ christopher painter - yes i have just tried that - i added a string value of "[TARGETDIR]myapp.exe" to the location HKPU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Run but that does not work either - it actualy adds this value to HKPU\SOFTWARE\WOW6432node\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Run

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is your case
[Adding registry key in C# shows when I read it back, but not in regedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541053/adding-registry-key-in-c-sharp-shows-when-i-read-it-back-but-not-in-regedit)

**How to confirm**
As suggested in comments, use ProcMon util and the result for key Read/Write operation in case of redirection will be **REPARSE**.